# What's this popup I saw for a couple seconds near my name?

Tags: bug, status-completed

I was navigating around doing my usual thing when upon a refresh I saw a popup box I've never seen before saying "The question you're asking appears subjective and is likely to be closed".

I don't have any questions that I'm asking, so I'm not sure what the deal with this is.

[image]

Like I said, I've never seen anything like this one before so what is it? :)

Comment: That's definitely a bug. You get this message when you type a question title like "How do you… ?" or similar.

Comment: @slhck Perhaps a couple streams got crossed in a cache someplace then, it went away (either after I clicked it, or just refreshed the page, can't remember exactly) and hasn't been back, nor could I suggest a way to reproduce it.  If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll happily accept it - you've told me what I wanted to know. :)

Comment: So tempted to change this tile to read "What's the best popup I saw for a couple seconds near my name?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We added validation warnings a few weeks ago ([here's an example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268446/floating-point-is-broken-duplicates/268459#268459)), but they were mainly for asking/answering questions, not editing, so... the next build will remove title/body warnings on edit.